# Getting a "NotImplementedError" in wxPython

Tags: python-2.7, wxpython

I'm getting this error whenever I run my wxpython code.

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "musicplayer.py", line 203, in <module>
        MyPanel(frame, -1)
      File "musicplayer.py", line 17, in __init__
        self.mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
      File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/wx-2.8-gtk2-unicode/wx/media.py", line 96, in __init__
        _media.MediaCtrl_swiginit(self,_media.new_MediaCtrl(*args, **kwargs))
    NotImplementedError
```

My program is to create a music player in wxpython.

Here is the code:

```
  import wx

    import wx.media

    import os

    from wx.lib.wordwrap import wordwrap





    class MyPanel(wx.Panel):

    def __init__(self, parent, id):

    

    wx.Panel.__init__(self, parent, id)

    self.SetBackgroundColour("white")

    self.Center()

    self.panel = wx.Panel(self, wx.ID_ANY)

    #self.CreateStatusBar()

    

        try:

            self.mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)

        except NotImplementedError:

            self.Destroy()

            raise

        

    

        

       

        loadButton  = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('icons/stock_media-file.png'),pos=(10,2))

        loadButton.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onLoadFile, loadButton)

        

        

        

    #   self.sb = self.CreateStatusBar()

        

        

    

        

        

        

       

        playlistButton  = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('icons/stock_media-list.png'),pos=(80,2))

        #playlistButton.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.OnWidgetEnter)

        

        



        helpButton  = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('icons/stock_media-help.png'),pos=(150,10))

        helpButton.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.onHelp, helpButton)

        

        #sb.SetStatusText("blabla")



        playButton  = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('icons/stock_media-play.png'),pos=(50,140))

        playButton.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onPlay, playButton)



        pauseButton  = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('icons/stock_media-pause.png'),pos=(130,140))

        pauseButton.Bind(wx.EVT_ENTER_WINDOW, self.onPause, pauseButton)

        

        

        

        stopButton = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('icons/stock_media-stop.png'),pos=(170,140))

        stopButton.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.onStop, stopButton)



        volumeButton = wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('icons/stock_media-volume.png'),pos=(1200,140))

        volumeButton.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.mute, volumeButton)



        



        nextButton=wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('icons/stock_media-next.png'),pos=(90,140))

        nextButton.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.playForward, nextButton)

        

        

        previousButton=wx.BitmapButton(self, -1, wx.Bitmap('icons/stock_media-previous.png'),pos=(10,140))

        previousButton.Bind(wx.EVT_LEFT_DOWN, self.playBack, previousButton)

        



        

        

       





                # layout ...

        hsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.HORIZONTAL)

        

        # also creates a border space

        vsizer = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)

        vsizer.Add(hsizer, 2, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=-10)

        vsizer.Add(self.mc,6, wx.EXPAND|wx.ALL, border=30)

        self.SetSizer(vsizer)

      

        #slider

    self.slider = wx.Slider(self,-1,pos=(10,100),size = (1350,-1))

        self.slider.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER,self.Seek)

    self.info_pos = wx.StaticText(self,-1,pos=(1300,125),size=(450,-1))

    sizer= wx.GridBagSizer(5,5)

    sizer.Add(self.slider,(1,1),(1,4))

        self.Show()



        #volumeslider

        currentVolume = 50

        global slider1

        slider1 = wx.Slider(self,pos=(1250,150),size = (100,-1))

        slider1.SetRange(0, 100)

        slider1.SetValue(currentVolume)

        slider1.Bind(wx.EVT_SLIDER, self.setVol,slider1)

        

        #Timer

        self.timer = wx.Timer(self)

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_TIMER, self.onTimer)

        self.timer.Start(100)



        start_image = wx.Image("Logo.gif") 

    start_image.Rescale(320, 300) 

    image = wx.BitmapFromImage(start_image) 

    mypic = wx.StaticBitmap(self, -1, image, pos=(550,300), style=wx.BITMAP_TYPE_PNG)

       

        ext = ("~~~Title~~~")

        self.file = wx.StaticText(self, -1, ext,size=(355,-1),pos=(600,175))



               

    def onLoadFile(self, evt):

        dlg = wx.FileDialog(self, message="Choose a media file",

            defaultDir=os.getcwd(), defaultFile="",

            style=wx.OPEN|wx.CHANGE_DIR )

        if dlg.ShowModal() == wx.ID_OK:

            path = dlg.GetPath()

            self.doLoadFile(path)

        dlg.Destroy()

        

    def doLoadFile(self, path):

        if not self.mc.Load(path):

            wx.MessageBox("Unable to load %s: Unsupported format?" % path,

                "ERROR", wx.ICON_ERROR | wx.OK)

        else:

            folder, filename = os.path.split(path)

            self.file.SetLabel('%s' % filename)

            self.GetSizer().Layout()

            self.mc.Play()

        

    def onPlay(self,event):

        self.mc.Play()

        self.slider.SetRange(0, self.mc.Length())

        self.mc.SetLabel('length: %d seconds' % (self.mc.Length()/1000))

             

    def onPause(self, evt):

        self.mc.Pause()

        self.sb.SetStatusText('Load file')

        event.Skip()

    def onStop(self, evt):

        self.mc.Stop()



    def Seek(self,event):

       self.mc.Seek(self.slider.GetValue())    



    def onTimer(self,event):

        current = self.mc.Tell()

        self.info_pos.SetLabel(" %i seconds" % (int(current)/1000))

        self.slider.SetValue(current)





    def setVol(self, event):

        currentVolume = slider1.GetValue()

        print int(currentVolume)

        self.mc.SetVolume(currentVolume)



    def mute(self, event):

        currentVolume=0

        self.mc.SetVolume(currentVolume)

       

    def playForward(self,event):

        playbackrate=16

        self.mc.SetPlaybackRate(playbackrate)


    def playBack(self,event):

        playbackrate=-4

        self.mc.SetPlaybackRate(playbackrate)

        

    def OnWidgetEnter(self,e):

        name = e.GetEventObject().GetClassName()

        sb.SetStatusText(name+'widget')

        e.skip()
    

    def onHelp(self, event):

        info = wx.AboutDialogInfo()

        info.Name = "Media 89 Help and Support"

        

        info.Description = wordwrap(

            "This is an example of a help description of how to  "

            "use this music player!"

            "1.You can load your file "

            "2.You can play music"

            "3.Can check the playlist",

            350, wx.ClientDC(self.panel))

        info.WebSite = ("http://homes.soi.rp.edu.sg/101193/home.html", "Online Help")

        info.play = ["media 89 group"]

        info.do = wordwrap("created by media 89!", 500,

                                wx.ClientDC(self.panel))

        

        wx.AboutBox(info)

    


app = wx.PySimpleApp()

style=wx.DEFAULT_FRAME_STYLE^wx.RESIZE_BORDER

frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, "Media 89",style=style,size = (1500,1800) )

MyPanel(frame, -1)

frame.Show(True)

app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: It'd be worth if you go through and fix your code formatting - too many large gaps and bits missing from code blocks...

Comment: The code is not entered correctly here..

Comment: So, it may appear incorrect..
btw can you please tell me the reason for that error?

Comment: where are the bits missing?

Comment: There's bits outside the code block - inside the code block, there's sometimes 10+ lines between lines of codes - too much reading - plus your indentation is too much, or sometimes not present where it should be

Comment: can anyone figure out what the error is?

Comment: During one of the edits, some of the other users removed your badly formatted code to make your question readable. It may be beneficial to put the code back and make sure that the formatting is correct and readable (eg. remove blank lines, gaps etc).

Comment: I have tried to repair this question by adding the code back again. Nevertheless, I shall also try to close it as "Needs Detail or Clarity".

Answer (score 1):

The wxMediaCtrl is an optional part of the build, and it will automatically be excluded if wxWidgets' configure script was not able to finde the right dependent libraries or their -devel packages are not installed.  When wxPython is built using a wxWigets without wxMediaCtrl then it creates a stub class that simply raises NotImplementedError if you try to use it.

Answer (score 0):

What version of wxPython?

On Linux, using python2.7 and wxPython 2.8.12.1, I went to my shell and started the python interpreter and issued some test commands:

```
python
>>> import wx.media
>>> app = wx.App()
>>> frm = wx.Frame(None)
>>> mc = wx.media.MediaCtrl(frm, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)
>>>
```

No error, although it took about 20 seconds after hitting enter on that last line and getting the python prompt back. Can you do the same at your command shell and see if you still get the error, and if so try without the style argument?