# wxMediaCtrl excluded during the installation

Tags: python, wxpython

I am trying to play video with wxpython. However, it is not working for me. I get `NotImplementedError` for the line below.

wx.media.MediaCtrl(self, style=wx.SIMPLE_BORDER)

The solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14302005/not-implemented-error-in-wxpython) tells that The wxMediaCtrl is an optional part of the build, and it could be automatically excluded while installing. The answer does not say how to include `wxMediaCtrl` while installing. I used `pip install wxPython` to install wxpython and it seems to be working. However, `wxMediaCtrl` seems to be excluded. So how can I include it while installing?

Comment: Try setting `szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_WMP10` (windows), `szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_GSTREAMER` (Linux) or `szBackend=wx.media.MEDIABACKEND_QUICKTIME` (Mac)

Answer (score 0):

You are probably missing some of the library dependencies needed to support the media classes. If you're on Linux then it's likely the gstreamer and/or gstreamer plugins. You can look at pip's build output in the area where it's running the configure script for wxWidgets for clues about what may be missing. (You may need to add --verbose to see the complete build output.)

See https://wxpython.org/blog/2017-08-17-builds-for-linux-with-pip for more info.